# Hide all active tooltips in java swing

Tags: java, swing, tooltip

I've encountered a funny situation (a bug?) in Java Swing. We've got a table that show's tool tips on each cell in case that the content can't be properly displayed due to overlength. If we somehow manange to open a dialog right when the tooltip shows up, it's drawn above the dialog, even if that dialog is modal. The even crazier thing is, that the tooltip isn't application modal, but system modal. For example, it even stays on top of the browser or word, as you can see here:

[image: tooltip above browser]

Ignore the incorrect encoding though, that's a different matter. I've been wondering whether there's anything I could do about this. The only thing that came to my mind was trying to hide all tooltips. But the only way I could think of, was iterating over all components and trying to hide the tooltip on each component manually. However, this is probably not gonna be very performant, as a complex GUI can have quite some depth.

While this might be a bug in the JDK, I'd like to be able to apply a workaround either way. Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: *I've encountered a funny situation* - post an [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Even a complex GUI won’t be costly to traverse.  How many components could one window have?  Even if it’s 100 or 500 components, traversing them, checking each for a tooltip, and hiding that tooltip will collectively take a small fraction of a second.